# Load CSS/Javascript in frontend conditionally if block is used

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, block-editor

Assuming I have no infinite scroll or anything else going on in my theme:
Is there a way to enqueue my custom Gutenberg block styles and scripts so they are only (lazy) loaded in the front-end when the block is really used? Something like `is_active_widget`, just for blocks?

If I enqueue them inside a `enqueue_block_assets` function they're added to any site.

On github, I found this https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/5445 , but it sounds like it's more on bundling than conditional load, so I still hope they didn't leave that optimization opportunity out - otherwise any other site will soon be junked with 20 additional scripts from numerous Gutenberg block plugins people install and only use once on a page (think of large image gallery block scripts for example).

Thanks & Regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks @kuchenundkakao for pointing me into the right direction. I'm still answering my own question as I want to give some more context for others that may stumble upon this.

So, there are several ways to load your custom blocks, mainly:

- `add_action('enqueue_block_assets','xy_function')` / `add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets','xy_function')`, which at the
  moment is the default when creating a block with
  "create_guten_block". This is what I was using. It might change, see
  https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block/issues/21
- `register_block_type` as per the handbook, see https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/tutorials/block-tutorial/writing-your-first-block-type/#enqueuing-block-scripts

While registering the block in PHP (like described in the handbook) is the default method and future proof, the `enqueue_block_assets` variant can load multiple blocks without the need to split your blocks into seperate files and define them again in PHP. "create_guten_block" for example merges any number of blocks into three files by default (blocks.build.js, blocks.editor.build.css and block.style.build.css).

Both ways do **not** conditionally load styles (yet).

When using the create_guten_block method, `enqueue_block_assets`, and only having a single block defined (or set up to split the files per block), the conditional loading can be added using `has_block`:

```
    function my_awesome_blocks_cgb_block_assets() {
      if (is_singular()) {
        $id = get_the_ID();
        if (has_block('my-awesome/block-type', $id)) {
            wp_enqueue_style(
              'my-awesome_blocks-cgb-style-css',
              plugins_url( 'blocks/dist/blocks.style.build.css', __FILE__ ),
            );
        }
      }
    }
    add_action( 'enqueue_block_assets', 'my_awesome_blocks_cgb_block_assets' );
```

You can combine register and conditional loading by leaving out the style / script parts in the register and load the according fontend files with enqueue_block_assets as in the code above.

The future proof method will be using `register_block_type`, as the `script` and `style` fields of it will most likely be used if conditional loading is ever implemented natively (see comment [here](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/11231)).

Comment: and where does the `register_block_type` go? is it just left out? @user127091

Comment: seems not to work when the block is converted to a reusable block!

Comment: Correct, the [has_block()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_block/) function currently cannot detect what blocks are used within a reusable block since the Gutenberg markup for the reusable block contents doesn't live on the page—it only contains a reference to the reusable block reference ID. Example of reusable block Gutenberg markup '<-- wp:block {"ref":23393} /-->'

Answer (score 17):

Well, the styles and scripts you register in your php register_block_type call should only be loaded when the block is in use if i recall correctly.

If you want to load additional scripts or styles to be enqueued only if there is a block of type "my-awesome/block-type", you can use the has_block function in your wp_enqueue_scripts function like this:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_if_block_is_present');

function enqueue_if_block_is_present(){
  if(is_singular()){
     //We only want the script if it's a singular page
     $id = get_the_ID();
     if(has_block('my-awesome/block-type',$id)){
        wp_enqueue_script('my-awesome-script',$path_of_script,$needed_scripts,$version_of_script,$load_in_footer);
     }
  }
}
```

If you also want the script to be loaded on multiple views as well (like category archive or the blog page), you can hook into the the_content filter and enqueue the script there:

```
add_filter('the_content','enqueue_my_awesome_script_if_there_is_block');

function enqueue_my_awesome_script_if_there_is_block($content = ""){
  if(has_block('my-awesome/block-type')){
        wp_enqueue_script('my-awesome-script',$path_of_script,$needed_scripts,$version_of_script,true);
   //Be aware that for this to work, the load_in_footer MUST be set to true, as 
   //the scripts for the header are already echoed out at this point
     }
   return $content;
}
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 9):

Another way is to [enqueue them inside the block's `render_callback()` function](https://mkaz.blog/wordpress/conditionally-load-block-assets-part-2/).

```php
register_block_type( 'mkaz/test-block', array(
    'editor_script'   => 'mkaz-test-block-script',
    'render_callback' => function( $attribs, $content ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'mkaz-test-block-client-asset' );
        return $content;
    }
) );
```

In the past it was invalid to enqueue stylesheets outside of `<head>`, but that's supported by the spec now.

x-ref: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/21838

Comment: Strangely enough apparently the `render_callback` is executed even on the Admin console when the content is being edited, so an `if ( ! is_admin() ) { ... }` check may need to be wrapped around the `wp_enqueue_script(...)`, if one only wants to enqueue that script when the block is being rendered in the frontend.

Comment: I think that's because of https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/18394

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @IanDunn works, but only for custom blocks, since you overwrite the render callback of existing blocks otherwise. You can use the [`render_block_{$this->name}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/render_block_this-name/) hook to include your script/stylesheet conditionally and check for all the block attributes whether your conditions apply.

An example conditionally adding a style for the `core/group` block:

```
static function my_group_callback( string $block_content, array $block ): string {
    if ( ! $condition ) { // check your condition
        return $block_content;
    }
    
    \wp_enqueue_style( 'my-handle', $uri ); // adjust handle and uri
    
    return $block_content;
}

\add_action( 'render_block_core/group', 'my_group_callback', 10, 2 );
```